# How to apply methods to capturing groups in re.sub

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

I want to replace a part of a string using `re.sub()` however I can't find a way to apply methods to the capturing groups. My code looks like this (bearing in mind that this is just for reproduction and is not my actual problem):

```py
import re

mystring = 'Hello NICE to meet you'
mystring = re.sub('(Hello )(NICE)( to meet you)', r'\1' + r'\2'.lower() + r'\3', mystring)
print(mystring)

>>> Hello NICE to meet you
```

In the above example, `lower()` does not affect `r'\2'`, is there any way to get this `re.sub` to return 'Hello nice to meet you'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a function instead of a string as replacement. It take the match object as argument, and should return the replaced string, as explained in [the documentation for re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
import re

def replace(match):
    return match.group(1) + match.group(2).lower() + match.group(3)


mystring = 'Hello NICE to meet you'
mystring = re.sub('(Hello )(NICE)( to meet you)', replace, mystring)
print(mystring)
# Hello nice to meet you
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just wanted to capitalize the sentence, you can use `str.capitalize`:

```
"hello NICE to meet you".capitalize()
>>> 'Hello nice to meet you'
```

If you want more than that, and dynamically play with the values of matched regexs:

The `re.sub` function accepts a handler as the replacement value for the matched regex. the handler should receive one parameter which is of type `re.Match`.

here is an example that lowercase words:

```
import re

def handler(match):
    return match.group(1).lower()

re.sub('([A-Za-z]+)', handler, mystring)
```

Comment: This makes the whole sentence lowercase rather than just 'nice'

Comment: @7koFnMiP I wasn't really sure if you only need that specific case or more than that, please take a look at my solution now and if it's still doesn't what you need - please give me a better explanation

Comment: Please see the accepted answer, this code returns ````hello nice to meet you```` rather than ````Hello nice to meet you```` and as I mentioned in the question the example given is just for reproduction; my actual problem does not involve capitalization